# Sync offline changes to a workspace into Perforce

Tags: perforce

I am trying to figure out what commands I need to run in order to get the changes to a workspace (add, edit, delete) into Perforce when the changes were made to the local system.

I have another version control system that holds the files for which I am trying to:

1. Get Changeset from other system
2. Write Changelist to the local system
3. Tell Perforce to create a change list for all the Add's, Edit's and Delete's in the folder
4. Check them in

I can achieve #1 and #2 using a [PowerShell Adapter for the TFS Integration Platform](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/configuring-a-powershell-adapter-for-the-tfs-integration-platform/), but how do I achieve #3 and #4?

I have tried [Working Disconnected From The Perforce Server](http://kb.perforce.com/article/2) and it has not worked for me. Whatever commands I need to call need to be run from PowerShell.

I can however call a PowerShell command for each of the changes "Add | Edit | Delete" individually if I need to but it would be nice if I could just call one set of commands after all of the changes have been made locally.

I effectively want to achieve the same as the "Reconcile Offline Work" command in the UI.

- **Does anyone know how to achieve this?**

I have had a stab at it with the following PowerShell run at the following time:

- Initilise:

  cd C:\temp\TestRun1
  echo Abcd1234 | p4 -u tfspoodrop -C utf16le-bom -Q winansi -p p4svr:1992 -c TfsSync login
  p4 -u tfsoutput -C utf16le-bom -Q winansi -p p4svr:1992 -c TfsSync sync ...
- Add File:

  p4 -u tfsoutput -C utf16le-bom -Q winansi -p p4svr:1992 -c TfsSync Add $IpNewPath
- Edit File:

  p4 -u tfspoodrop -C utf16le-bom -Q winansi -p p4svr:1992 -c TfsSync edit $IpNewPath
- Commit:

  p4 -u tfspoodrop -C utf16le-bom -Q winansi -p p4svr:1992 -c TfsSync submit -d $IpChangeGroup.Comment ...

I am hoping that his is all there is to it, and I know that I still need to take into account Branches and Renames, but does anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach described in Working Disconnected From The Perforce Server is the right approach; you just need to work through the details to run it from PowerShell (or automate it using some other approach, which you then in turn invoke from PowerShell).

Comment: It is the Add command that does not work in PowerShell as the DIR command has different output. (I probably need a PowerShell questions for that though)