# Perforce deleting a file from workspace and reflecting that in Perforce

Tags: excel, vba, perforce

Is it possible to delete a file from your workspace and then hitting submit in perforce and that file being deleted from the perforce server?

```
open for read: F

\LocalSource\Perforce\MainBranch\blah\New Text Document.txt: The system cannot find the file specified. 

Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 4799463'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
```

I get this message when I try to submit. In Subversion I could do this. I had a look on the internet and it looks like this isn't possible, but I thought I'd check on here.

(The reason I want this is because I have a spreadsheet and I want to extract the modules from the spreadsheet and put them into source control. But sometimes modules in that spreadsheet may be removed and I want to be able to just checkin the modules that are changed and do deletions on the server, without having to go into the perforce client and deleting the files marked for deletion in there.) One method was to delete all the files in perforce and then do a dummy commit of an empty directory. And then add all the files again extracted from the spreadsheet and do an add. But then in my version history I always will have a version with a full delete.

Any simple ideas, special commands that I can use?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

If you delete files directly on disk, without using the Perforce client to delete them (e.g., you use your spreadsheet command to delete those files directly), that's called "offline work", and in order to tell Perforce that you've made those changes, you just need to go back into your P4V window and use "Reconcile Offline Work".

See [Working Disconnected From The Perforce Server](http://kb.perforce.com/article/2) for complete instructions.

See also this related question: [Sync offline changes to a workspace into Perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458927/sync-offline-changes-to-a-workspace-into-perforce?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Perforce has a **command-line client** (http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_commandline_client) you should be able to execute from Excel as any exe file via the **Shell** function.